# Can't save textarea to file using php?

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have issue saving textarea to file. I used POST method to send the form to the other page then, in the next page I can't include the textarea content with the file Im not sure what is the problem.

Is there any idea about what is the problem?

Here are the two pages:
page1:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Save</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <span>name:</span>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <span>file extension: </span>
    <select name="ext" id="ext">            
        <option value=".txt">.txt</option>
        <option value=".doc">.doc</option>          
    </select>
    <textarea name="txt1" id="txt1" cols="15" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Save">
          </form>
          <br>
</body>

  </html>
```

-page2.php

```
$txt1 = $_POST['txt1']; //textarea
$name = $_POST['name'];
$ext = $_POST['ext'];  //choose from multiple extensions
if ($ext == '.txt')    // In case if I want to add more than extension.
{   
    $file = "'. $name$ext.'" ;
    $output = "$txt1";
    file_put_contents($file, $output);
    $text = file_get_contents($file);

    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: application/text/plain");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your html part (<form>)

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` looks correctly to you?

Comment: Not that it actually matters for the logic, but you are reading the file twice, once with `file_get_contents()` and once with `readfile()`.

Comment: I added the html form I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

`$file = "'. $name$ext.'";`

should be:

`$file = $name.$ext;`

At least that's what I had to change to get it to work on my server.

Comment: Thanks.. I can download the file, but It shows no content inside.

Comment: any suggestion, how can I get the content of the textarea to be inside the file?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your html I can't be sure of what the problem is.  But its been my experience that when your having trouble accessing POST vars on the server side that it's probably a simple spelling error.  Make sure the name attributes in your form line up with your POST vars.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what did you mean with your code, so, I'd just rewrite it

To save a file on the server you need these 2 lines

```
$name = basename($_POST['name']).'.txt';
file_put_contents($name, $_POST['txt1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an id to the form, then add the form Id to the textarea element. For example:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post" id="myform">
    <textarea name="txt1" id="txt1" cols="15" rows="10" form="myform"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the wrap element in your textarea

```
<textarea name="txt1" id="txt1" cols="15" rows="10"></textarea>
```

add wrap

```
<textarea name="txt1" id="txt1" cols="15" rows="10" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
```

you can also use wrap: off, hard, soft and physical

In your database make sure the field txt1 is defined properly (i.e type text).